# I can't read jQuery-UI widget factory options from a privat method

Tags: jquery-ui, widget, factory

I'm new with the jQueryUI widget factory, therefore it may be silliness what I'll ask.
I'd like to create an ajax tooltip where I can set the url of the ajax call through an option but this option is not readable in the _mouseOver method which contains the ajax call.

> ```
>     (function($) {
>         $.widget("ui.tooltip", {
>    options: {
>         url: ''
>     },
>   _create: function() {
>       alert(this.options.url); //it works
>       this.element.bind({
>         mouseenter: this._mouseOver
>       });
>     },
>   _mouseOver: function() { 
>       alert(this.options.url); //it dosen't works
>     },
>   ...
> ```
>
> As I setup: 
>   $(".text").tooltip({url: "something" });

Can somebody help me, please.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.tooltip", {
        self: null,
        options: {
            url: ''
        },
        _create: function () {
            self = this;
            self.element.bind({
                mouseenter: self._mouseOver
            });
        },
        _mouseOver: function () {
            alert(self.options.url); // it should work
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Using "this" inside _mouseOver refers to a current object inside the event function and not to the widget itself. You should create a variable and put the widget (this) on it, to be able to use it options in any event or method.
You will find the same behavior when using a $.each() function in jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "this" context of _mouseOver function is element and not jquery widget. That's why you don't get options.url.

You can try using this code as a start:

```
_create: function() {
      alert(this.options.url); //it works
      this.element.tooltip = this;
      this.element.bind({
        mouseenter: this._mouseOver
      });
    },  
_mouseOver: function() { 
  alert(this.tooltip.options.url); //it dosen't works
},
```

It's not tested.

Comment: Not works, but:
that: null,
_create: function() {
  that = this;
  ...
}
_mouseOver: function() {
  alert(that.options.url);
  ...