# Jquery ui Autocomplete 1.9 source function access options

Tags: jquery-ui

In the function I define for the source option of jquery ui autocomplete 1.9.1, I want to access the options of the jquery ui autocomplete.

From inspecting "this" inside this function, I found that I can access options using this.options. I wonder if this is the right way to do it, so that I'm not relying on internal specifications ?

Answer (score 0):

I made this working like this. There should be easier way, but I didn't find it.

```
<script>
    $('#element').autocomplete({
        self: null,
        myOption: 'test',
        source: function (request, response) {
            self = this;
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($('#combobox').children("option").map(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                    return {
                        label: text.replace(
                            new RegExp(
                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                        value: text
                    };
            }));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(self.options.myOption);
        }
    });
</script>
<html>
    <input type="text" id="element" />
    <select id="combobox">
        <option value="t1">Python</option>
        <option value="t2">PHP</option>
        <option value="t3">ASP.NET</option>
        <option value="t4">C++</option>
        <option value="t5">Ruby</option>
    </select>   
</html>
```

Hint found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498367/i-cant-read-jquery-ui-widget-factory-options-from-a-privat-method)

check it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f7qvu/1/